# SQL Select Duplicate Values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following database structure Tables in the database
[image: Tables in the database]

If a user from USER_TABLE has duplicate data in the ADDRESS_TABLE table and they are both active, one of the ACTIVE records should be changed to 0. Examples of duplicate data are highlighted in red. That is, in the ADDRESS_TABLE table, you need to change the activity of one of the records with numbers 14 or 15 and 18 or 19. And in the DOCUMETNS table, the documents related to the records from the table above are record 2033 or 1400 and record 3000 or 3001. Each record in the ADDRESS_TABLE table and the DOCUMETNS table has a common INFID - a table with data about the recording time.
I tried to do this, but I get an extra value.

```
SELECT DISTINCT at.INFID, ut.UID FROM
  ADDRESS_TABLE at
  INNER JOIN users_table ut on ut.UID = at.UID
  INNER JOIN DOCUMENTS doc on ut.UID = doc.UID
  WHERE
ut.rowid <>
(
  SELECT
    MAX(ad.rowid)
  FROM
    ADDRESS_TABLE ad
    WHERE

    at.HOME = ad.HOME AND
    at.APP = ad.APP AND
    at.INDEX = ad.INDEX AND  
    at.ACTIVE = 1 and ad.ACTIVE = 1 HAVING count(*) > 1


)   ORDER BY ut.UID;
```

Comment: It's not that important, but the latest addition is better

Comment: So what have you attempted?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I update question. I tried to get first INFID value, and then change values ACTIVE based on these INFID on UPDATE command. But I'm not quite sure what I did right, and I get INFID = 1400, 1401, 1500, 1501.  It is necessary to remove the excess from the my select command. For example 1401, 1501.

Comment: Just add 1 more condition in your subquery as `at.INFID = ad.INFID `

Comment: @AnkitBajpai but then I can't find anything.

Comment: First I understood your request as: in case of active duplicates in addresses and documents update rows to active = 0, so there are no active duplicates anymore, But then you are showing a mere select statement, not update statements. So do you want updates or not? And I don't understand why you mention INFID. Does it have anything to do with the task? If so, what?

Comment: For future reference - please do not post images of code or data - include the code or data in your question as text. That way people who'd like help you can copy the text and work with it. Thanks.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner
That's right, first I want to select "IFNID" duplicate addresses on user from ADDRESS_TABLE. And since the repeated "address" and "document" has the same INFID. The next step I will do is UPDATE ADDRESS_TABLE at SET at.ACTIVE = 0 WHERE at.INFID in (1401, 1501);
UPDATE DOCUMENTS doc at SET doc.ACTIVE = 0 WHERE doc.INFID in (1401, 1501);
I decided to divide it into several stages to make it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` to check whether another active row exists with the same values.

```
update address_table a
set active = 0
where active = 1
and exists
(
  select null
  from address_table other
  where other.uid = a.uid
  and decode(other.home, a.home, 'same', 'different') = 'same'
  and decode(other.app, a.app, 'same', 'different') = 'same'
  and decode(other.index, a.index, 'same', 'different') = 'same'
  and other.active = 1
  and other.id > a.id 
);

update documents d
set active = 0
where active = 1
and exists
(
  select null
  from documents other
  where other.uid = d.uid
  and decode(other.contract_type, d.contract_type, 'same', 'different') = 'same'
  and other.active = 1
  and other.docid > d.docid 
);

commit;
```

I am using `DECODE` here to include nulls in my equality check. If you want standard SQL instead, make this `and (other.home = a.home or (other.home is null and a.home is null))` etc. If the column is not nullable, then `and other.home = a.home` suffices and should be preferred.

I am updating all active rows where an active sibling with a higher ID exists. If you want to make this "where an active sibling with a higher *INFID* exists", then just change the two lines.